# Is there a simpler way to bind the entire match when using multiple matches?

Tags: syntax, rust, pattern-matching

Binding a variable to a match expression can be done by using `@` and a variable name, like:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Foo {
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    Fourth,
}

fn bar(f: Foo) {
    match f {
        e @ Foo::First => println!("{:?}", e),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

If you want to bind `e` to multiple matches, you have to repeat the binding on every possibility.

```
fn bar(f: Foo) {
    match f {
        e @ Foo::First | e @ Foo::Second | e @ Foo::Fourth => println!("{:?}", e),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: I don't understand how this makes any difference. Now you can simply use `f` instead of `e`, and remove all the `@` bindings. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Maybe you're just right and I should use `f` instead... :/

Comment: Nested 'OR' patterns will be possible eventually: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54883.

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks for the pointer! The [corresponding RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2535-or-patterns.md#guide-level-explanation) makes clear that `foo @ (1 | 2 | 3)` will be possible as well – for subpatterns this is actually useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In Rust 1.53 and above](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/79278), you can nest 'or' patterns like so:

```
fn bar(f: Foo) {
    match f {
        e @ (Foo::First | Foo::Second | Foo::Fourth) => println!("{:?}", e),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: As of mid 2022, RFC is approved and it now works (at least from rust 1.63.0)

Comment: @MaksimGayduk: Thanks for the heads up, I've updated my answer to reflect that :)